# JS countdown clock not counting down

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a countdown clock on my page, it works in this snippet but not on the testing page and I'm not sure why as I have just copied over the same code.

Here is the test page I am trying it out on: https://www.gkunions.co.uk/test/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 33 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

});
```

```css
h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00BF96;
    display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00816A;
    display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see your javascript code included in your html

Comment: Where do you include your js ?

Comment: @Kevin.a I found, it is in scripts.js

Comment: It's in the <head> of the page

Comment: Can you include the js after your relevant html?

Comment: I think you have a problem in other scripts, because it works just fine by copy-paste, see https://jsfiddle.net/wxsgeowy/ - but why use Date.parse all the time? Just use `.getTime` function to get the timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've debugged your code and found that for some reason `deadline` initialises wrong, at the beginning of the Unix era. Change:

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 33 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

to:

```
var deadline = new Date().getTime() + 33 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

and change:

```
var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
```

to:

```
var t = endtime - new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: hi, thanks, it still doesn't seem to work on my page though

Comment: @Stephan Unverwerth noted, `Date.parse` method doesn't work on your page for some reason. So you need to fix it or not to use `Date.parse`. I will update my answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

Some script on your page overwrites the `Date.parse` method, which then returns `null` and causes the wrong date to be generated.